# Why the y-axis value type double is automatically generated such labels?

Tags: c#, charts

I have this table.
Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrBlo.png
In this table.
I'm doing a chart and that's what got.
Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wcZ6.png

Why for double type  got such labels axis y? What am I doing wrong?
In Series for XValueType I set type double, it could not.

Comment: Maybe your chart drawing tool doesn't recognize decimal separator of values. It is possible that ',' is treated as thousands separator and that's why your double type values are so big numbers.

Comment: Post the code of how you setup the chart, and how you add points to it. Sounds like maybe the language localization isn't set up properly, as mentioned, so it's not recognizing the comma as a decimal point.

Comment: `CultireInfo.InvariantCulture` will certainly do the trick